# setTimeout delay not functioning - what have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've put together a piece of code for a drop-down menu, bound to `.hover()`, however unfortunately the delay on `setTimeout()` doesn't seem to work and as soon as the mouse is moved from `.button`, it sets the display property of `#sub-nav` to `none`.

Dreamweaver CS 5.5 evaluates the syntax as correct :(.

**Here's my code:**

```
function retract(){ $('#sub-nav').css('display', 'none'); }

$('#header-restrict > .button').hover( function() {

  if($(this).html() == "Offers") {
      $('#sub-nav').css('display', 'block');
      $('#sub-nav').html('<a href="#">Add a New Offer</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Edit an Offer</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Get Offer Links</a>');
  }

  if($(this).html() == "Rotations") {
      $('#sub-nav').css('display', 'block');
      $('#sub-nav').html('<a href="#">Add a New Rotation</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Edit a Rotation</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">Get Rotation Links</a>');
  }
}, function() { setTimeout(retract(), 4000); });
```

If anyone could comment on/answer as to why the delay doesn't seem to be working, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, no real developer uses Dreamweaver (or for that matter, any other WYSIWYG editor).

Comment: @Hello71 - Thanks for the sidenote. I only use Dreamweaver for front-end stuff, mostly because I've gotten use to it (in code mode only, I never even look at design mode). As you may have guessed, I'm not a regular user of Javascript, hence why I'm not really concerned with having a dedicated editor for it with syntax evaluation, code prediction etc as a feature. Rest assured though, when I develop in PHP I use a solid IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(retract(), 4000)
```

should be

```
setTimeout(retract, 4000)
```

The former immediately executes `retract`, then passes its return value (namely `undefined`) to `setTimeout`. Since `undefined` is not a function, `setTimeout` attempts to convert it into a string and `eval` it, doing precisely... nothing.

The latter says "run the function `retract` 4000 ms from now."